# Doing conditionals on multiple HTML checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements, multipleselection

So I had done a previous post on the same question, but I deleted that post and simplified my codes further and corrected some errors. So my objective here is to give a suggestion of players based on the attribute and skills that are chosen.

```js
function random() {
  var a = document.getElementById("Position").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = a;
  if (a) {
    console.log("Great Choice");
  }
}

var val = 0,
  form = document.forms.skills,
  text = skills.elements.type;
form.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");
  text.value = "";
  Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      text.value += checkbox.value + "\n";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
  <h1>NBA Draft Prediction</h1>
  <br>
  <a href="default.asp">
    <img src="https://basketball91.com/files/2013/06/basketball-positions.gif" alt="Daruis Garland" style="float:centre;width:300px;height:300px;" align="middle">
  </a>
  <br>
  <h2> Choose the required position </h2>
  <select id="Position" onchange="random()">
    <option>Choose Position</option>
    <option value="Scoring Guard">Scoring Guard</option>
    <option value=" 3 & D Guard">3 & D Guard</option>
    <option value="Passing Guard">Passing Guard</option>
    <option value="Forward">Scoring Forward</option>
    <option value="3&D Forward">3 & D Forward</option>
    <option value="Scoring Center">Scoring Center</option>
    <option value="Defending Center">Defending Center</option>
    <option value="Ring Protector">Rim Protector</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <br> You have Chosen the position of:
  <div id="output"></div>

  <br>
  <h2> Choose the required Skills</h2>

  <form name="skills" method="post">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j1" value="Height" class="anyclass"/> Height</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j2" value="Weight" class="anyclass" /> Weight</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j3" value="ArmLength" class="anyclass" /> Arm Length</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j4" value="FingerLength" class="anyclass" /> Finger Length </label><br>
    <h3>You have chosen:
      <textarea name="type" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>
```

Kindly ignore the comments made here.
For example, suppose a user chooses a "Scoring Guard" like position. The user selects Attributes as "Height" and "Weight". Based on these selections I would want to have an output as a text, say "Player1".

Any suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: It's not clear how the input would correspond to the output "Player1"? Do you have an array or similar of players that you want to match to the inputted criteria/positions?

Comment: @BrettGregson Yes, we plan to have an array of players initially with various attributes.

Comment: Without that part, I'm not sure what the question is?

Comment: But how to do conditionals on multiple selection in html. Maybe say, if I choose "Height" and "Weight", atleast I need an output of "Great Choice".

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>NBA Draft Player Suggestion</title>

</head>
<!--<style>
body {
  background-image: url('Img3.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;  
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
-->

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">




  <h1>NBA Draft Prediction</h1>
  <br>
  <a href="default.asp">
    <img src="https://basketball91.com/files/2013/06/basketball-positions.gif" alt="Daruis Garland" style="float:centre;width:300px;height:300px;" align="middle">
  </a>
  <br>
  <br>





  <br>
  <h2> Choose the required position </h2>
  <select id="Position" onchange="random()">
    <option>Choose Position</option>
    <option value="Scoring Guard">Scoring Guard</option>
    <option value=" 3 & D Guard">3 & D Guard</option>
    <option value="Passing Guard">Passing Guard</option>
    <option value="Forward">Scoring Forward</option>
    <option value="3&D Forward">3 & D Forward</option>
    <option value="Scoring Center">Scoring Center</option>
    <option value="Defending Center">Defending Center</option>
    <option value="Ring Protector">Rim Protector</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <br> You have Chosen the position of:
  <div id="output"></div>

  <br>
  <h2> Choose the required Skills</h2>

  <form name="skills" method="post">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j1" value="Height" class="anyclass"id="ch1"/> Height</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j2" value="Weight" class="anyclass" id="ch2"/> Weight</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j3" value="ArmLength" class="anyclass"  id="ch3"/> Arm Length</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="j4" value="FingerLength" class="anyclass" id="ch4"/> Finger Length </label><br>
    <h3>You have chosen:
      <textarea name="type" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>

      <button name="btn" onclick="random()">Get Result</button>




      <!--<br>
<a href="NBA_2nd_Page.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Click Here To Go To Next Page</a>
-->
<script>
var val = 0,
    form = document.forms.skills,
    text = skills.elements.type;
form.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");
  text.value = "";
  Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(checkbox) {

    if (checkbox.checked) {
      text.value += checkbox.value + "\n";
    }
  });
});
function random() {
  var a = document.getElementById("Position").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = a;

  if(a == 'Scoring Guard'  && document.getElementById("ch1").checked == true && document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true){
    alert('Player1'); 
  }

}

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should add an Id to each checkbox and then check what has been checked and display your required value. I hope in your case you do not have many conditions because that you could result writing a lot of conditions. The best option would be to use machine learning for prediction. You can build your own model according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it and see if its possible. And yes, there are lot of conditionals required